# Antialias font-face embedded text in Windows?

Tags: antialiasing, font-face

Is there any way to make the fonts render as anti aliased in Windows, when using font-face embedding?

http://code.google.com/webfonts looks much better on Ubuntu/Mac, as compared to Windows 7 (tried chrome/firefox)

Comment: Looking at them with the magnifier they *are* anti-aliased, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no Anti-aliasing present for embedded fonts in any version of Windows yet.

Comment: They are anti-aliased, just not very well.

Comment: How does this explain the fact that embedded fonts on Windows look fine when ClearType is turned off?

Answer (score 10):

I just found a great solution for this old problem. If you *serve the svg format of your font before woff*, Chrome on windows will anti-alias and render your font properly.

I'm using this technique on my demo page [here](http://keyamoon.com/icomoon/#toDemos). You can see the headers and the icon fonts are all smooth and properly anti-aliased.

Comment: Serving svg first means it should be called *lastly* (after other formats) in the @font-face rule, right?

Answer (score 3):

above recommendations to turn on cleartype are sadly incorrect.  Cleartype makes embedded fonts jagged – turning clertype OFF makes them smooth.  i don't know why this is, but it sure is frustrating.

Comment: I just tried this, after wondering why my embedded fonts look so awful on Win7 and so great on my WindowsXP VM (which doesn't have ClearType set). And you're absolutely correct, I've just turned clear type OFF and as I type the text looks terrible, everywhere the fonts look absolutely horrible. However, my embedded fonts that looked horrible in all browsers suddenly now appear smooth... I'd like to get to the bottom of this - and find way around it if possible. I can't expect all my Windows users to turn off clear type for my fonts to look smooth. This is a pretty crazy result.

Answer (score 2):

This should force Chrome on Windows to anti-alias:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.05deg);
```

I'm not aware of any solution for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've got clear-type turned on. Thats-anti aliasing for your windows.

Comment: As mentioned in my experiment above (I can provide evidence if necessary) it is only when you TURN OFF ClearType, that embedded fonts (at least the fonts I am using) appear smooth. I confess, this doesn't seem to make any sense, but it happens.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the css3 font smoothing

```
font-smooth: auto | never | always | <absolute-size> | length | initial | inherit
```